# How do I apply a range of parameters to a range of functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, time-series, octave

I'm trying to generate some time series data using MATLAB, with the help of a model that looks like this:

> Y(t)=phi*Y(t-1)+mu+E(t)

Where **phi** and **mu** are constants and **E** is a normally distributed random number (white noise).
I came up with this piece of code, which does the job perfectly.

```
E=randn(1,20);mu=1;phi=0.2;Y=zeros(1,20);
Y(1)=mu*phi+mu+E(1)
for t=2:20;
Y(t)=(Y(t-1))*phi+mu+E(t);
endfor; Y=Y'; plot(Y)
```

This creates a set of values where the first one uses mu as a seed and after that (the next 19 values) are generated based on the output of the last Y.

It's just perfect, however, now I'm trying to use different values of **phi** ranging (0,1) to apply the exact same algorithm.
I came up with this:

```
E=randn(1,100);
mu=2; phi=linspace(0.1,0.99,10)';p=(2:10)';Y=zeros(10,100);
Y(:,1)=mu*phi(1)+mu+E(1)
for t=(2:100);
   Y(:,t)=(Y(:,t-1))*phi(p)+mu+E(t)
endfor
```

Which, according to my logic is saying:

'Apply the same algorithm that generates a single set Y to every value "p" of phi', so it should output 100 Y's for every p.

However, I'm only getting dimensional errors, and once, while fiddling around sort of worked, but I just ended up with one long 100*100 matrix of zeros and the first value as the correct result.
I'm trying to plot every Y set to visualize the effect of phi over the model, but I'm burned out now.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks to Floris SA, the final program ended up being:

```
E=randn(1,100);
mu=2; phi=linspace(0.1,0.99,100)'; Y=zeros(100,100);
Y(:,1) = mu*phi + mu + E(1);
for t=(2:100);
   Y(:,t) = Y(:,t-1).*phi + mu + E(t);
end
```

I modified her code to get a different plot with:

```
for ii = 2:100
 semilogy(Y(1,:));hold on; semilogy(Y(ii,:))
end
```

Which produced this (exactly what I was looking for; in Spanish):
[image: Phi customizing for every Y]

Comment: This is (a chunk of) one of the things I tried,but it's ugly, time consuming and i don't think it is the best way to do it. For this i used phi=[0.9 0.6] and mu=[2 3], ergo the variable names: Y209(1)=phi(1)*mu(1)+mu(1)+E(1);
Y206(1)=phi(2)*mu(1)+mu(1)+E(1);
Y309(1)=phi(1)*mu(2)+mu(2)+E(1);
Y306(1)=phi(2)*mu(2)+mu(2)+E(1);
for t=linspace(2,100,99)
Y209(t)=(Y209(t-1))*phi(1)+mu(1)+E(t);
Y206(t)=(Y206(t-1))*phi(2)+mu(1)+E(t);
Y309(t)=(Y309(t-1))*phi(1)+mu(2)+E(t);
Y306(t)=(Y306(t-1))*phi(2)+mu(2)+E(t);
endfor;
plot(Y209);hold on; plot(Y206);plot(Y309);plot(Y306);

Comment: I think as a start you don't need the p vector of indices, just multiply by phi. (also in the initialization of Y).

Comment: do you know the difference between * and .*?

Comment: I guess i didn't but somehow decided to ignore it. Now i know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. In your code block:

```
E=randn(1,100);
mu=2; phi=linspace(0.1,0.99,10)';p=(2:10)';Y=zeros(10,100);
Y(:,1)=mu*phi(1)+mu+E(1)
for t=(2:100);
   Y(:,t)=(Y(:,t-1))*phi(p)+mu+E(t)
endfor
```

It looks like you want to try 10 values of `phi`. First, I suspect you want to change this line (left your version, right the new one):

```
Y(:,1)=mu*phi(1)+mu+E(1);  -->  Y(:,1)=mu*phi(:)+mu+E(1);
```

Since you want to associate each of the `10` rows of `Y` with a specific value of `phi`, right?

Next, you declare `p` to be 9 values long, so `phi(p)` will also contain 9 values. `Y(:,t-1)` for any `t` contains 10 values. This means these are both vectors, and when you do multiplications involving two vectors, you have to be careful with what operators you use. When Matlab sees two vectors multiplied, it will try to do a [vector multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_of_vectors), which it cannot do in this case because of two reasons:

- `Y(:,t-1)` is of length 10, whereas `phi(p)` is of length 9. This is why you are probably getting a dimension mismatch error.
- `Y(:,t-1)` is a column vector, and so is `phi(p)` in your case. Vector multiplication of two column vectors is not defined.

What you want instead is to multiply each **value** in `Y(:,t-1)` with the **value at the same index** in `phi`, which you do by using [element-wise multiplication](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) with `.*`:

```
Y(:,t)=(Y(:,t-1))*phi(p)+mu+E(t)  -->  Y(:,t) = Y(:,t-1).*phi + mu + E(t);
```

This should fix your errors.

If you want to plot the values in Y later, you could use [`imagesc`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) to do that. Example of full code, with plotting with `imagesc`:

```
E=randn(1,100);
mu=2; phi=linspace(0.1,0.99,10)'; Y=zeros(10,100);
Y(:,1) = mu*phi + mu + E(1)
for t=(2:100);
   Y(:,t) = Y(:,t-1).*phi + mu + E(t);
end
figure(); imagesc(1:100,phi,Y); colorbar; xlabel('t-values'); ylabel('phi-values');
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i needed. I ended up modifying the plotting part to get the one i'm required to, and I also modified it to get 100 values of phi rather than 10. I'm updating my question to show the result.